Jenkins ext mail attachments type (mime-type)
I'm using Email Ext to send emails with the resuls of my Jenkins builds.
I've noticed that the build log has an attachmet type of plain text while any other attachment I'm adding is marked as octect stream.
Is there a way to make all my attachments plain text?
Thanks
